# Word Frequency Chart Problems

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The goal of this code was to create a program using main method java to analysis a piece text which has been entered from a user.

They do this by entering the text into a scanner which is then analysed by the program. The analysis is to produce word frequency, mean length and also print out the results in a form of a asterisks chart, were a single "*" represents 1 words.

For example " Birds can maybe fly" produces this results:

```
Enter text: 
Birds can maybe fly
Birds can maybe fly
1 letter words: 0
2 letter words: 0
3 letter words: 2
4 letter words: 0
5 letter words: 2
mean lenght: 4.0

1 letter words
2 letter words
3 letter words **
4 letter words
5 letter words **
```

So far I've completed the word frequency and the word mean, but the part I'm stuck on is creating the asterisks chart. This is an area in which I've never touch upon and was wondering how I would go about it, would I use a histogram or just use my int and then print out a "*" instead of a number?. I'm not expecting anyone to just hand me code, but if someone could give me a hint in what I should do or just point me the right direction or maybe just give me an explanation in what I should do, it would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Freq
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true)
        {

            System.out.println("Enter text: ");

            String s;
            s = scan.nextLine();
            String input = s;
            String strippedInput = input.replaceAll("\\W", " ");

            System.out.println("" + strippedInput);

            String[] strings = strippedInput.split(" ");
            int[] counts = new int[6];
            int total = 0;

            for (String str : strings)
                if (str.length() < counts.length)
                    counts[str.length()] += 1;
            for (String s1 : strings)
                total += s1.length();
            for (int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++)

                System.out.println(i + " letter words: " + counts[i]);
            System.out.println(("mean lenght: ") + ((double) total / strings.length));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Commons Lang StringUtils.repeat()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Usage:

```
 String str = "*";
 int n = 2;
 String repeated = StringUtils.repeat(str, n);
```

repeated will be: ****

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop over `counts` and for each cell print a number of asterisks equal to the number stored in it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; ++i) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(i).append(" letter words ");
    for (int j = 0; j <= counts[i]; ++j) {
        sb.append('*');
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```